# How to include external javascript in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, certification

I bumped into these questions today with the list of these possible answers, but only two answers should be correct?

```
<apex:includeScript>
<link>
<apex:define>
<script>
```

I am confident with *apex:includeScript* and *link* but I m not sure are those correct>

Comment: Apex:includeScript and script. Link is for css, and apex:define is using for visualforce template composition

Comment: how you call it from script? Would you mind to write it in answer section.

Comment: example:
**<script src="/files/tutorial/browser/script/rabbits.js"></script>**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the Visualforce `apex:includeScript` results in the HTML `<script src="..."></script>` being output in the `head` element of the page i.e. before any of the visible page elements. That means that the page rendering is likely to be delayed while the JavaScript is pulled in and executed.

Directly using the HTML `<script src="..."></script>` gives you control of when the JavaScript is pulled in and executed. Generally it is best to do that at the end of the page so the user sees the page content as soon as possible:

```
<apex:page>

    ...

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Your JavaScript that uses jQuery
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:includeScript value="any link"/>
```

you can also use static resources here like

```
 <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MyJavascriptFile}"/>
```

can be used to include javascript same as

link tag is used to reference css.
define tag is used when you are creating page layouts and partial views.

```
You answer is <apex:includeScript/> and <script/>
```

reference 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_templates_composition.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm

Answer (score 0):

Answers are a & c

A) 
To include external Javascript file in Visualforce page, follow the below steps

1. Add the JS file in Setup --> App Setup --> Develop --> Static Resources.
2. Add the below code in your Visualforce page

   **`<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Resource_Name_of_JS_File}"/>`**

C)

```
**<script url="your URL" />**
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit the below link which will help you.You need to create a static resource by the way :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_javascript_intro.htm

Comment: Please do not post link only answers - see [answer]

Answer (score 0):

The correct options are

```
<apex:includeScript>
<script> tag
```

The `apex:includeScript` renders as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resource_url"></script>
```

and the main thing to **note** when using visualforce tag is that it injects the script reference into the `<head>` element of the generated HTML page.